# Python C Extension Missing Function

Tags: python, python-extensions

While following a C extension for Python tutorial, my module seems to missing its contents. While building and importing the module have no problem, using the function in the module fails. I am using Python 3.7 on macOS.

`testmodule.c`

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    const long long x, y;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "LL", &x, &y)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromLongLong(x + y);
}

static PyMethodDef TestMethods[] = {
    {"add", add, METH_VARARGS, "Add two numbers."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef testmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "test",
    NULL,
    -1,
    TestMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_test(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&testmodule);
}
```

`setup.py`

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('test', sources=['testmodule.c'])

setup(name='Test',
      version='1.0',
      description='Test package',
      ext_modules=[module1])
```

The test and error are

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.add(4, 5)
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: @DYZ This solved the problem. Thanks so much for pointing this error out to me.

Comment: Will post the comment as an answer for the sake of preservation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you imported the standard module `test` (check `test.__path__`). If so, rename your module.